# Установить цвета на кнопку через вторую активность с помощью экз.класса.SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Как установить цвета на кнопку через вторую активность с помощью экз.класса.SharedPreferences ?**

Первая активность:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_color1);

    btnAct = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAct);
  

    SharedPreferences preff = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ToolColor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int Color = preff.getInt("Color", R.color.colorWhite);

    btnAct.setBackgroundColor(Color);

    btnAct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityColor1.this, MainActivityColor2.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

Вторая активность:

```
private Button btnRed;
SharedPreferences preff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_color2);

    btnRed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRed18);

    preff = getSharedPreferences("ToolColor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    btnRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preff.edit();
            editor.putInt("Color", R.color.colorRed);
            editor.commit();
            BackButton();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: ToolBarColor и ToolColor. Эти строки должны быть одинаковы. Точно не помню, возможно, мод должен быть не приватным, но это либо в доку слазить, либо методом тыка проверить.

Comment: Моя ошибка, не заметил, но всё равно дело не в этом. Спасибо что заметили.

Comment: Я вот не помню, onCreate вызывается у активности второй раз при возвращении на нее? Может, стоит попробовать изменение цвета в onResume перенести?

Comment: 1)у SharedPreference есть есть листнеры, можете свой код перетащить в него. когда один инстанс запишет данные, другой получает уведомление об измененном значении (и само значение). 2) Вы можете запустить активность с ожиданием результата startActivityForResult(...), и ваш цвет передавать в результат через setResult.

Comment: Спасибо, проблему уже решил. Проблема была в том что нужно было воспользоваться не putInt() а putString().